# How can I change the dateformat of dateColumn in react-datasheet-grid

Tags: reactjs, date, format, datasheet

I want to change the date format to "dd-mm-yyyy".
But when I am using DateSheetGrid and set the column to dateColumn, the type always "mm-dd-yyyy".
How can I fix it?
Please help me.

I have tried to set the component to the column and also tried createTextColumn.
But I cannot implement it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.